# Bayesian network inference using logistic regression and mcmc

Tags: logistic, markov-chain-montecarlo, bayesian-network

I have a small Bayesian network and I am trying to understand the results after applying some observed value / evidence.

I have a net like below

[image]

where $Y \in \{0,1\}$, $P(X) \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$, and $logit(p) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X$ . (Y nodes are related to X nodes by logistic regression).

If I add evidence that $Y = 1$ , then I expected that $p$ would also equal one; as $p$ is the probability that $Y_{2} = 1$, and as $Y = 1$ then I expected $p$ to equal one. Why is it not please?

I have added some code below to illustrate.

---

```
library(rjags)

mod <- 
"model {
      # logit node
      y  ~ dbern(p)
      logit(p) <- -1 + 1*x

      # priors
      x ~ dnorm(0.5, 1/0.5^2)  
}"    

# evaluate network after setting evidence on node y, that is set y = 1
jg <- jags.model(textConnection(mod), n.adapt = 1000, data=list(y = 1), 
                 inits=list(.RNG.seed=1, .RNG.name="base::Wichmann-Hill" )) 

update(jg, 10000)
cs1 <- coda.samples(jg, c("x", "p", "y"),  1e4)
summary(cs1)
```

Which gives

```
#      Mean     SD Naive SE Time-series SE
# y  1.0000 0.0000 0.000000       0.000000
# p  0.4185 0.1106 0.001106       0.001338
# x  0.6527 0.4784 0.004784       0.005815
```

Comment: Are you really assuming $\beta_0, \beta_1$ are known? What are your parameters here? And what is $X$?

Comment: @Taylor ; yes, the network is fully parameterised, and in the example code  $\beta_{0} = -1$ and $\beta_{1} = 1$. X is a normally distributed variable, with prior distribution $\sim N(0.5, 0.5^{2})$ (dnorm(0.5, 1/0.5^2)  in the code). I would use this to make inference on the network, like P(x < 2 | y = 1) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there are some inconsistencies with your notation. I myself had some difficulty differentiating between your observations, parameters, and latent variables. But I think the answer to your question will be: "it's because of Bayes' rule."

Observe that:
$$
P(x|y) \propto P(y|x)P(x). 
$$
When you set $y=1$, then  $P(y|x) = \text{invlogit}(x + 1)$. So your posterior density, which your jags program samples from, is proportional to the pointwise product of these two functions (functions of $x$).

The quantity $p$ is just a transformation of $x$. You can transform your samples $x^1, x^2,\ldots$ into $\text{invlogit}(x^1 + 1), \text{invlogit}(x^2 + 1), \ldots$, and you will have samples from the distribution $P(p|y=1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to tidy up my notation - the parameters in the text should match the names in the code, and the only observation / evidence added is $y=1$.